# Logic for online Quiz (What type of person are you)

Tags: logic

I have created an online quiz which has 12 questions. Each question has exactly 4 options to choose as an answer.

At the end of the quiz the idea is to send them to one of 4 thank you pages that have statement's such as "You answered mainly 'a' you are this type of person"

However I'm struggling to come up with the logic. The software (TypeForm.com) I'm using offers two options for logic.

Logic Jumps = If/Else statements with optional (and unlimited) AND/OR statements. 
Calculator = Allows you to assign a score to each answer.

How do I assign the right final screen using these options? Currently I have this setup:

Assign all answer a)'s a score of 1

Assign all answer b)'s a score of 2

Assign all answer c)'s a score of 3

Assign all answer d)'s a score of 4

On the final answer there is a logical jump that has the logic:

**"If 'Score' is equal to '12' then jump to 'custom end A'"**

However this does not work unless the quiz taker answered a) everytime, which is highly unlikely.

We do have the following other options available to us:

**'is lower than or equal to'**

**AND**

**'is higher than or equal to'**

So we can create a range that an answer could possibly fall between.

The other option is to choose the logic: 
If answer to Q1 is equal to a) AND If answer to Q2 is equal to A etc... until you have added all the different variation
But I think the amount of different variations for this would be way too much to setup?

Anyone help me with this? p.s. if this is off topic I apologise it has already been removed from MathStack and they advised I try here.

P.S. the software does not allow you to make use of variables in order to keep a count, which was suggested by someone on the Math forum.

Answer (score 0):

Well this solution is a terrible hack but it should work fine for 12 questions. Assign the following numbers to your answers:

```
score A = 1
score B = 100
score C = 10000
score D = 1000000
```

Now, given the total score you can patiently check all possibilites (order matters)

```
if (score >= 03000000 and score <= 99999999) then D
if (score >= 02030000 and score <= 02999999) then C
if (score >= 01030000 and score <= 01999999) then C
if (score >= 00030000 and score <= 00999999) then C
if (score >= 02020300 and score <= 02029999) then B
if (score >= 02010300 and score <= 02019999) then B
if (score >= 02000300 and score <= 02009999) then B
if (score >= 01020300 and score <= 01029999) then B
if (score >= 01010300 and score <= 01019999) then B
if (score >= 01000300 and score <= 01009999) then B
if (score >= 00020300 and score <= 00029999) then B
if (score >= 00010300 and score <= 00019999) then B
if (score >= 00000300 and score <= 00009999) then B
otherwise A
```

This is really ugly, but given your limitations it's hard to come up with an elegant solution.